# How should I upgrade Python on CentOS 5.5 (64-bit)

Tags: python, centos5, yum

I believe I am running CentOS 5.5 (64-bit) on CA AppLogic 3.0.

`uname -a` says

```
Linux LINUX64 2.6.18-194.32.1.el5xen #1 SMP Wed Jan 5 18:44:24 EST 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have upgrade with `yum upgrade`, but my Python is still in version 2.4.3.

`yum info python` says

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.5ninesolutions.com
 * extras: mirrors.cmich.edu
 * updates: mirror.5ninesolutions.com
Installed Packages
Name       : python
Arch       : x86_64
Version    : 2.4.3
Release    : 46.el5
Size       : 72 k
Repo       : installed
Summary    : An interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language.
URL        : http://www.python.org/
License    : PSF - see LICENSE
Description: Python is an interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming
           : language often compared to Tcl, Perl, Scheme or Java. Python
           : includes modules, classes, exceptions, very high level dynamic data
           : types and dynamic typing. Python supports interfaces to many system
           : calls and libraries, as well as to various windowing systems (X11,
           : Motif, Tk, Mac and MFC).
           :
           : Programmers can write new built-in modules for Python in C or C++.
           : Python can be used as an extension language for applications that
           : need a programmable interface. This package contains most of the
           : standard Python modules, as well as modules for interfacing to the
           : Tix widget set for Tk and RPM.
           :
           : Note that documentation for Python is provided in the python-docs
           : package.
```

I think I read once somewhere that `yum` depends on `python` so I shouldn't remove that. So should I download python version 2.7.x as a source and compile it? Or is there a way to upgrade Python with `yum` (somehow)?

I am planning using the latest version 2.x of Python for Django.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's `python26` package available from [epel repo](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL). It should be better and easier option then installing manually.

However, please note that you probably won't be able to replace default `python` with 2.6 or any other version, as there are a lot of stuff build for 2.4 and upgrading it would require you to rebuild lots of packages and resulting system would not be really CentOS 5. I think it's easier to upgrade to CentOS 6 then to rebuild so much packages.

Answer (score 2):

Yea compile it from source:

```
yum install gcc gcc-c++.x86_64 compat-gcc-34-c++.x86_64 openssl-devel.x86_64 zlib*.x86_64
```

install python 2.7

```
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7/Python-2.7.tar.bz2
tar -xvjf Python-2.7.tar.bz2
cd Python*
./configure --prefix=/opt/python27
make
make install
vi ~/.bash_profile

replace PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
with PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/opt/python27/bin
```

reload .bash_profile

```
source ~/.bash_profile
echo "/opt/python27/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/python27.conf
ldconfig
```